# Live Stream video using Android with pure java

Tags: java, android, video, live-streaming

i am trying to do a live streaming app in android, my question is what is the difference between using http and rtsp is there any way to only java code to do this, i refer so many projects already done are using java with other language combination, is there any way to stream in efficient way using java only

Answer (score 9):

RTSP means *Real Time Streaming Protocol*, is a protocol specifically designed for streaming purpose, with RTSP you can control absolute positioning within the media stream, recording and possibly device control etc

- RTSP introduces a number of new methods and has a different
     protocol identifier.

  - An RTSP server needs to maintain state by default in almost all
    cases, as opposed to the stateless nature of HTTP.
  - Both an RTSP server and client can issue requests.
  - Data is carried out-of-band by a different protocol.

If you want to use video streaming you have to use RTSP

See this [LINK](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt) for more details about the protocol RTSP

NB

To show the video content in Android you can use the VideoView

```
myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myview);
myVideoView.setVideoPath("rtsp://SERVER_IP_ADDR:5544/");
myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
```

As described [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Comment: @Silverstrom is there any tutorial about how to implement RTSP in android

Comment: @appu bala I don't know android rtsp tutorial link, however I have added a tips to my question, hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go for RTMP (Real time messaging protocol) instead of RTSP, there are number of open source plugins available in the market, like the famous "flowplayer" which is capable of streaming the video as per the industrial standards using the RTMP protocol. It has rapidly developed its capability to stream videos on Apple devices with the existing Flowplayer source plugin. Hope this helps

Flowplaye : [flowplayer website](http://www.flowplayer.org)
We are currently using the Akamai streaming capability coupled with flowplayer plugin for a flawless streaming experience.