# Best way to stream video files from Server to Android App

Tags: android, video-streaming

I have a few `mp4` files on my server. And in my Android App, I want the user to be able to stream those videos.

It seems very simple in start. But it became painful when I tested it on different devices. I tried several different methods. I first tried it through `intent`

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
startActivity(i);
```

This streams the video in any video player installed on user's phone. But the problem with this is that this method doesn't work with many video players. For example it doesn't work in VLC. So, I had to think of another way.

Then I tried it with VideoView. That worked on many devices. But on Android 2.2 and 2.3 devices it's not working and giving `MediaPlayer error (1, -2147483648)` Error.

Is there any standard and simple way of streaming the videos on all Android versions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262094/android-is-there-a-way-to-stream-video-on-a-app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049338/live-stream-video-using-android-with-pure-java

Comment: @RachelGallen | I've mentioned that I already tried VideoView. But it's not working on all versions of Android. I am looking for a way (may be some third party library) that will allow me to stream the videos on all versions of Android.