# Android video streaming client RTSP

Tags: android, video-streaming

I am trying to build an app to play video from an URL, I am using rtsp, I have tried with most of the examples that I have found online, however none has worked.. This is my code so far in the client:

```
package com.example.rtsp_player;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String uri = "rtsp://192.168.2.170:5544/";
    VideoView v = (VideoView) findViewById( R.id.videoView );
    v.setVideoURI( Uri.parse(uri) );
    v.setMediaController( new MediaController( this ) );
    v.requestFocus();
    v.start();
}
}
```

And this is how I am broadcasting using vlc:
        *:sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=800,fps=30,width=320,height=180,acodec=mp4a,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=22050} :rtp{sdp=rtsp://192.168.2.170:5544/}***

I don't know if it is because of the codecs or what..

Comment: mmm I guess nobody has an answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myview);
myVideoView.setVideoPath("rtsp://SERVER_IP_ADDR:5544/");
myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049338/live-stream-video-using-android-with-pure-java/14049373#14049373) may help

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your code.

**Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,"1");**

Change the code like this and try.

```
String uri = "rtsp://192.168.2.170:5544/";
VideoView v = (VideoView) findViewById( R.id.videoView );
Uri uri_add = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,"1");
v.setVideoURI( uri_add.parse(uri) );
v.setMediaController( new MediaController( this ) );
v.requestFocus();
v.start();
```

Comment: Is not `Uri.parse` static? If yes, we don't use any uri_add manipulations here...